When the program finishes drawing , I want it to draw a shape that surrounds the drawn shape
I'm currently creating a react design 2d room; The room interior space will be designed by clicking and dragging, the drawing will be finished with the last line back to the starting point, and I'm using react Konva. What I want is to draw an exterior wall with a wall thickness of 20 when the client finishes drawing. Let me explain more, assume that the client has drawn a line that forms a square room
const [points, setPoints] = useState([
    100, 100, 500, 100, 500, 500, 100, 500, 100, 100,
  ]); 

This will draw one line that starts from 100, 100 to 500,100 then to 500, 500 to 100,100, and then will draw a square room. What I actually want is to have an exterior wall (a line that surrounds the drawn square room), that line should have these points [80, 80, 520, 80, 520, 520, 80, 520, 80, 80], then I want to draw a line between the first point in the drawn line (100,100) with the first point of the exterior wall line (80,80), then another line between the second point in the drawn line (500,100) to the second point of the exterior wall line (520,80), and so on, this will create walls in which the walls will fit each other when they meet. Hope you understand, and I appreciate any help.
(I have tried creating many functions in which I can place the exterior wall points, and it all failed horribly.)
